# UIActionSheet, how to dismiss it with a single click?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet

UIActionSheet, how to dismiss it with a single click?
I have to click a button 2 times so it gets dismissed, what should I do to make it dismissble after the first click?! Here is my code:

```
-(void)buttonHeld:(id)sender
{



    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete Contact?!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [popupQuery showInView:self.view];
    [popupQuery release];




}
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {


  if (buttonIndex == 0) {

 NSLog(@"Delete button clicked Button Clicked");


    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

   NSLog(@"Cancel Button Clicked");
   } 

}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem. When I first click a button on the ActionSheet it is calling the correct method in actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex: but the button doesn't highlight blue and the sheet doesn't dismiss. Not until I click the button again for the second time does it highlight and then dismiss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a few taps to get it to cancel as well. The problem ended up being which view I attached it to.

```
[action showInView:self.view];
```

self.view was only referenced in IB.  I changed it to a different view and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the name of your method "buttonHeld", my assumption is that you are trying to launch the UIActionSheet from a UILongPressGestureRecognizer. You will need to use the code listed below if you want it to work as expected. The problem stems from UILongPressGestureRecognizer being a 'continuous gesture' which fires multiple times and progresses through several different states. You'll need to monitor for the correct state and then load your UIActionSheet. I had the exact same problem and this is what solved it for me.

```
- (IBAction) buttonHeld:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                                      initWithTitle:@"Delete Contact?!" 
                                           delegate:self 
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                             destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" 
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

        popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
        [popupQuery showInView:self.view];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this was the correct answer too. I can confirm this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is how i dismiss the actionsheet...

```
  [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

No need to declare in this delegate when you alloc the actionsheet you have make cancel Button that by default dismiss the ActionSheet some thing like this

```
[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:btnTitle,@"Send for a date range",nil];
```

from any other event you can use this method

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
```

In your code there is a syntax error you are putting else block in if block.

Answer (score 0):

If u're developing for the iphone it's always safe to use :

> [popupQuery showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES]

or showFromTabBar: or showFromToolBar etc. instead of showinView.